# Using GROUP BY and UNION

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I have a table:

```
CODIGO  NOME     VIEW    EDIT
1       TESTE      1      1
1       TESTE      0      1
3       TESTE3     0      0
3       TESTE3     1      0
5       TESTE5     1      0
5       TESTE5     0      1
```

Hod do I build a query to get the following result in SQL SERVER?

RESULT:

```
CODIGO    NOME   VIEW   EDIT
1         TESTE   1       1
3         TESTE3  1       0
5         TESTE5  1       1
```

Comment: I can think of different queries that could run that result... What are the conditions of the query?

Comment: you have to elaborate on the logic of how the result data are produced

Comment: Welcome to SO, please be a bit more specific when asking question: what have you tried, what do you expect, etc. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Looks like a simple `select codigo, nome, max(view), max(edit) from the_table group by codigo, nome`

Comment: Sorry, overlooked something,

Comment: @Luiz | What do you want the condensed data to be?  For example, do you want the new `EDIT` column to be the highest value of the other `EDIT` column in each category?  Is it being used as a boolean value?  Many of the answers posted thus far will produce the example expected result, but what do you want the result to be in general?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use MAX() :

```
SELECT CODIGO, NOME, MAX(VIEW) AS VIEW, MAX(EDIT) AS EDIT
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY CODIGO, NOME
```

Comment: [Scott Mikutsky's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37544521/6281508) use SUM(), but in your example, 'Teste' ->  'EDIT' is 1 and not 2 !

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to group by CODIGO and NOME while getting de highest value of VIEW and EDIT. I'd try this:

```
SELECT CODIGO, NOME, MAX(VIEW) AS VIEW, MAX(EDIT) AS EDIT
  FROM TABLE
GROUP BY CODIGO, NOME
ORDER BY CODIGO, NOME
```

Answer (score 0):

Below query will give the required output :-

```
select distinct CODIGO,NOME,MAX(cast([VIEW] as int)) OVER ( Partition by CODIGO,NOME) [VIEW],MAX(cast(EDIT as int)) OVER ( Partition by CODIGO,NOME) EDIT     from table_name
```

Output :-

```
 CODIGO    NOME   VIEW   EDIT
 1         TESTE   1       1
 3         TESTE3  1       0
 5         TESTE5  1       1
```

NOTE : Have done casting for VIEW and EDIT column because if you are using bit data type for them, then MAX function will not support it.